# Apply same function over different dimensions of an multiple dimension vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, iterator, virtual

First, I'm sorry, I don't know a lot of c++, maybe my question is kind of stupid.
I have a multidimensional vector M. I want to be able to apply the same function either along the elements of a row i, or along the elements of a column j. I don't want to write the same function twice. It is possibly to do this in a rather simple way, like some overloading or with virtual iterators? can anyone write a simple example? thank you.

Comment: What does your multidimensional vector look like ?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to go about this would be to use `std::transform`. Consult this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) for more details. Short example with how to do this for rows is below. The column part is a little tricky.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int nRowCnt = 3, nColCnt = 3;

int RowFunc(int i) { return ++i; }
int ColFunc(int i) { return --i; }

void PrintArray(vector<vector<int>>& vecArray, int nRowCnt, int nColCnt)
{
    for (int nOuter = 0; nOuter < nRowCnt; nOuter++)
    {
        for (int nInner = 0; nInner < nColCnt; nInner++)
        {
            cout<<vecArray[nOuter][nInner]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector< vector<int> > vecVals(nRowCnt, vector<int>(nColCnt,0));    
    vector< int > rowOut(nColCnt*nRowCnt,0), colOut(nColCnt*nRowCnt,0);
    vector<int>::iterator itrOut;

    for (int nRow = 0; nRow < nRowCnt; nRow++)
    {
        for (int nCol = 0; nCol < nColCnt; nCol++)
        {
            vecVals[nRow][nCol] = nRow * (10+nCol) ;
        }
    }


    PrintArray(vecVals,nRowCnt,nColCnt);

    itrOut = rowOut.begin();
    for (int nOuter = 0; nOuter < nRowCnt; nOuter++)
    {
        std::transform(vecVals[nOuter].begin(),vecVals[nOuter].end(),itrOut,RowFunc);
        itrOut += nColCnt;
    }

    itrOut = colOut.begin();
    for (int nOuter = 0; nOuter < nRowCnt; nOuter++)
    {
        for (int nInner = 0; nInner < nColCnt; nInner++)
        {
            std::transform( vecVals[nInner].begin() + nOuter, vecVals[nInner].begin() + nOuter +1, itrOut,ColFunc);
            itrOut++;
        }
    }

    cout<<endl<<"Row Transformed"<<endl;
    for (itrOut = rowOut.begin(); itrOut != rowOut.end(); itrOut++)
        cout<<*itrOut<<" ";

    cout<<endl<<"Col Transformed"<<endl;
    for (itrOut = colOut.begin(); itrOut != colOut.end(); itrOut++)
        cout<<*itrOut<<" ";

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

There is a catch though, the column part won't work for non-square 2D arrays (i.e for it to work row and column counts must be the same). I guess this can be worked around with a little more thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can define you own iterator over the columns, so that you can use standard algorithms (like `for_each`, or `transform` as mentionned in another answer) to apply you function either to rows or columns of you array by just changing the iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Custom iterator to iterate over columns
//   to be adapted to the underlying storage
class ColIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, double>
{
public:
  typedef std::vector<std::vector<double> >    MDarray;

  ColIterator(MDarray & array, int i, int j) : array_(array), i_(i), j_(j) {}
  ColIterator(const ColIterator& it) : array_(it.array_), i_(it.i_), j_(it.j_) {}

  ColIterator& operator++() {
    ++i_;
    return *this;
  }

  ColIterator  operator++(int) {
    ColIterator tmp(*this);
    operator++();
    return tmp;
  }

  bool operator==(const ColIterator& rhs) { return &array_==&rhs.array_ && i_==rhs.i_ && j_==rhs.j_; }
  bool operator!=(const ColIterator& rhs) { return !operator==(rhs); }
  double& operator*() {return array_[i_][j_];}

private:
  MDarray & array_;
  int i_;
  int j_;
};


// a function
void mult2 (double & x) {
  x *= 2;
}



int main () {
  typedef std::vector<double>::iterator RowIterator;

  int nRows = 5;
  int nCols = 5;
  ColIterator::MDarray array (nRows, std::vector<double>(nCols, 1));


  // Apply function mult2 to column 3
  int col = 3;
  ColIterator beginCol (array, 0, col);
  ColIterator endCol   (array, nRows, col);

  std::for_each(beginCol, endCol, mult2);


  // Apply function mult2 to row 4
  int row = 4;
  RowIterator beginRow (array[row].begin());
  RowIterator endRow   (array[row].end());

  std::for_each(beginRow, endRow, mult2);


  // Check results
  for (int i=0 ; i<nRows ; ++i) {
    for (int j=0 ; j<nCols ; ++j) {
      std::cout << " " << array[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a 2D vector:

Rows will be straightforward:

```
const std::vector<int>& getRow( const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& input, int rowIdx )
{
    return input.at( rowIdx );
}
```

Columns a little trickier:

```
std::vector<int> getColumn( const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& input, int colIdx )
{
    std::vector<int> output;
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i )
        output.push_back( input.at( i ).at( colIdx ) );
    return output;
}
```

These functions basically take a 2D integer vector and return a row/column vector based on the specified index.

This is the basis for what you're trying to do (from what I can gather). Minor modification will allow you to apply a function to rows/columns selectively instead of merely returning them.

Comment: In the first case (rows), wouldn't it be better to return a `const std::vector<int>&`?

Answer (score 0):

If your multidimensional vector is an actual multidimensional vector, for example something like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, which isn't suggested, then you will have to write your own iterator. It's not very complicated. Boost.Iterator has concepts that can be used to help implement it.

If your multidimensional vector is a single vector with it's size set to the product of the dimensions (i.e. width * height), which is the preferred way to handle this, then it's much easier. It can be done with the utilities provided by Boost.Range.

Here's a quick and dirty example of using Boost.Range. It could be made a little prettier with `decltype`. If your compiler doesn't support C++11 (specifically `auto`), I wouldn't suggest using this, because the code becomes very hard to read.

```
template<typename T>
boost::iterator_range<typename T::iterator> 
GetRow(T& vec, typename T::size_type row, typename T::size_type w, 
typename T::size_type h) {
    return boost::make_iterator_range(
      vec.begin() + (row * w), 
      vec.begin() + ((row + 1) * w)
    );
}

template<typename T>
boost::strided_range<boost::iterator_range<typename T::iterator>> 
GetColumn(T& vec, typename T::size_type col, typename T::size_type w, 
typename T::size_type h) {
    boost::iterator_range<typename T::iterator> range = boost::make_iterator_range(
      vec.begin() + col, 
      vec.begin() + col + (h - 1) * w + 1
    );
    return boost::strided_range<boost::iterator_range<typename T::iterator>>(w, range);
}
```

And then using these functions is pretty easy, though again, it can become very ugly if your compiler doesn't support `auto`.

```
const size_t WIDTH = 3;
const size_t HEIGHT = 3;
std::vector<int> vec(WIDTH * HEIGHT);

// Fill the first row with 1.
auto row =  GetRow(vec, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
for (auto it = row.begin(); it != row.end(); ++it) {
    (*it) = 1;
}

// Fill the second column with 2.
auto col = GetColumn(vec, 1, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
for (auto it = col.begin(); it != col.end(); ++it) {
    (*it) = 2;
}

// Contents of vec is:
// 1 2 1
// 0 2 0
// 0 2 0
```

You may also want to look into Boost.MultiArray, which is a library intended for things like this. It provides the functionality you want, but it's definitely not the friendliest library.